# Font Awesome Styling Q (Buttons In-Line)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

This is kind of a silly question since there is a simple answer, but I am trying to use font-awesome buttons in-line, as shown in [this plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ss2zRtVUeYnJpJw3LDpO?p=preview)

If I do this:

```
            <td class = "col-xs-1">
                <span class="btn yellowFont fa fa-star"
                      title = "Set this as the item's primary case."
                      ng-if="!case.primaryCase">
                </span>

                <span class="btn redFont fa fa-times"
                      title = "Remove item from case."
                      ng-if="!case.primaryCase">
                </span>
            </td>
```

the "btn" class pushes the second font-awesome icon to a new line. I can avoid this by removing the `btn` class, e.g.

```
<span class="redFont fa fa-times"...>
```

But this removes the default hover-over behavior, which I want to keep.

Yet another solution is to have them in separate cells, but that makes the spacing between them far too wide (even 1/12 makes it too wide, and I don't know if I can further sub-divide table cells like I could with a normal grid, e.g. `col-xs-1` for the cell and then `col-xs-6` for each of the spans.

In short, is there a way to have the font-awesome icons in line, next to the "Case Name" column, while keeping the default hover-over functionality (Yes, I do realize I can easily add a "on-mouseover" event, it's just dirty.

Comment: Just do `<td class = "col-xs-3">` instead of `<td class = "col-xs-1">`

Comment: Yep, that does it, I thought btn was forcing a new line, but I guess btn just takes up more space. Thanks. Post it as an answer if you would like, since I already posted a Q and all. edit: "Danke, das..."works" gut." What would the phrase be? Kannst du sagen "Das geht" hier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the grid widths like shown below. In fact of the bootstrap grid should have 12 cols, take 3 and 9.

```
         <td class = "col-xs-3">
            <span class="btn yellowFont fa fa-star"
                  title = "Set this as the item's primary case."
                  ng-if="!case.primaryCase">
            </span>

            <span class="btn redFont fa fa-times"
                  title = "Remove item from case."
                  ng-if="!case.primaryCase">
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class = "col-xs-9">
                {{case.caseNumber}}
            </td>
```